# javascript validations for HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

Some one help me out in javacript validations for the form below where it should check no numbers/numericals shoud be there in fname and lname,
stnumber shoud have specific size (size)
state and pincode should match
is it possible with javascript validations?????

```
<form id="user" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
 <span>First Name:</span>                       
    <input type="text" class="input" id="fname" name="fname" required>
  <span>Last Name</span>
<input type="text" class="input" id="lname" name="lname" required>
  <span>Student Number</span>
<input type="text" class="input" id="stn" name="stn" required>
 <span>Student address</span>
<input type="text" class="input" id="stad" name="stad" required>
 <span>Town/suburb</span>
<input type="text" class="input" id="town" name="town" required>
 <span>State</span>
<select name="state" id="state">
<option selected>--select--</option>
<option>AAA</option>
<option>BBB</option>
    </select>                               
<span>Postal Code</span>
<input type="text" class="input" id="pcode" name="pcode" required>
```

Comment: Yes.. what does your JavaScript look like?

Comment: what you mean by javacript validator?

Comment: function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("First name must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
}

Comment: I recoment you to use jquery validate

Comment: no i shld not use jquery....i shld have only javascript

Comment: Can you first try it yourself, you are only checking if firstname is filled in but nothing else. If you need help, come back.

Comment: @user2802614: In what way does this fail?  When you debug this, what is the value of `x`?

Comment: no im nt getting any errors, i aint knw how to validate using javascript im a beginner

Comment: wht is the condition for not allowing any numericals in text area and to check length/size??

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If your project allowes you to, you could go for HTML5 validation using specific HTML5 attributes such as required, min, max and pattern. See more information on [W3Schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_attributes.asp) and [html5pattern.com](http://html5pattern.com/)

If Javascript is a requirement, there's an ample selection of validation libraries out there such as [jQuery Validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) or [Parsley](http://parsleyjs.org/) that are perfectly capable of doing what you want to achieve.

Comment: [Please, don't link to w3schools. It's a horrible reference full of incorrect information that sometimes even leads to security holes.](http://w3fools.com)

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand the question but if you want user to enter a "specific" size, why don't you just use

```
maxlength="size"
```

property?

EDIT: 
Javascript Part

```
  function isCharKey(evt){
       var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
       return !(charCode < 31 && (charCode > 48 || charCode < 57));
 }
 var state= document.getElementById("state").value;
 var pcode= document.getElementById("pcode").value;
if (state != pcode) {
    alert("State and Pcode doesn't match");
}
```

in your html

```
 <input type="text" class="input" id="fname" name="fname" required onkeypress="return isCharKey(event);">
 <input type="text" class="input" id="lname" name="lname" required onkeypress="return isCharKey(event);">
 <input type="text" class="input" id="stn" name="stn" required maxlength="10">
```

That should do it for entering only characters but not numbers

EDIT 2:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function isCharKey(evt){
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    return !(charCode < 31 && (charCode > 48 || charCode < 57));
}
function validateForm() {
    var state= document.getElementById("state").value;
    var pcode= document.getElementById("pcode").value;
    if (state != pcode) {
        alert("State and Pcode doesn't match");
    }   
}</script>
```

Write this at the bottom of your page

Comment: srry, text area telephone i need only 10 numbers above tht it should show alert....

Comment: and in normal fname and lname it should not allow numiricals i need condition fa tht can u plz help me thnq :)

Comment: There is no field like telephone? You need to post more of your code

Comment: srry its student number

Comment: i just gave example,,,,,

Comment: If that works, you can accept my answer, so other people will learn the way too. By the way you're very welcome

Comment: and how about using this??                                       var re = /\d/;
  if(re.test(user.fname.value)) 
  {
  document.getElementById("name1").innerHTML="Error: Numiricals are not allowed";
  }

Comment: At the end of the code just add <script type="text/javascript"> and  write that javascript part inside and then </script>

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">                                             function validateForm()
  {
  var re = /\d/;
  if(re.test(user.fname.value)) 
  {
  document.getElementById("name1").innerHTML="Error: Numiricals are not allowed";
  }                                                      </script>

Comment: no ok i can understand that.....wht i am asking is how about using this function...."above comment/code"

Comment: http://w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp You can check this out or you can search google for javascript regexp